# Transfer running instance of OS to another machine

Tags: suspend, init, hibernate

Theoretical question, but for example, is it possible to hibernate on a laptop and boot into that image on a desktop which could have otherwise identical configuration in terms of distro/config files.

The practical application for this would be to transfer all running programs from a laptop to a desktop for greater performance or vice versa for portability.

Is it possible to "pretend" to hibernate the OS and to copy all changed files to another computer.

I understand that this might not be practical but I want to hear your thoughts on if it is even possible using current technologies.

Comment: I wonder if it can be done with a numa cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed possible through the magic of virtualization. See, for example

https://www.usenix.org/legacy/event/hotos09/tech/full_papers/kozuch/kozuch_html/index.html

and

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_migration

which contains a list of virtual machine managers that support live migration.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know this was even an actual thing. Thanks!

Comment: Are there any real world implementations of migration without virtualization since I can't seem to find any. Also, on what scale of time is the copy process of live migration? minutes? hours?

Comment: The timescale depends mostly on the size of the memory and disk images of the machine being copied, but I would say on the order of minutes is close. As for non-virtual examples, I don't have any on hand. I think the pervasiveness and efficiency of modern virtualization techniques makes it less necessary. That being said, there are interesting tools for inspecting live running OSs like https://github.com/carmaa/inception